# No module named 'keras_text_summarization' when running keras-text-summarization

Tags: python, keras

I have cloned [keras-text-summarization](https://github.com/chen0040/keras-text-summarization), then was running according to [README.md](https://github.com/chen0040/keras-text-summarization)

`python seq2seq_train.py` and I get:

```
(testenv1) ➜  demo git:(master) python seq2seq_train.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seq2seq_train.py", line 5, in <module>
    from keras_text_summarization.library.utility.plot_utils import plot_and_save_history
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_text_summarization'
```

Note I have installed `requirements.txt` dependencies with:

```
(testenv1) ➜  keras-text-summarization git:(master) conda install --yes --file requirements.txt
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.4.8
  latest version: 4.5.4

Please update conda by running

$ conda update -n base conda
```

## All requested packages already installed.

I was expecting it to run as the documentation said: (this is what the documentation said, I used `conda` to install)

```
pip install requirements.txt

cd demo
python seq2seq_train.py
```

which is exactly what I did (except that I used conda instead of pip for the dependencies installation).

python env:

```
(testenv1) ➜  keras-text-summarization git:(master) python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Here is the content of requirements.txt:

```
requirements.txt:
scikit-learn
keras
tensorflow
pandas
numpy
scipy
h5py
matplotlib
```

I'm not using python on any regular basis maybe I'm missing something very basic?

Comment: Try installing requirements manually

Comment: but it's complaining about 'ModuleNotFoundError: 'keras_text_summarization' isn't keras_text_summarization part of the source code itself of the project and not one of the 'pip' dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder `keras_text_summarization` was outside the `demo` package.  So as it appears the documentation is incorrect. I needed the either to:

1. Install the `keras_text_summarization` by running setup.py on parent folder.
2. Move `keras_text_summarization` inside the demo folder.

I ran step 2 and it worked (moved `keras_text_summarization` inside the demo folder).

This means no external modules were missing and condo installation was perfect.

Comment: hi done exactly the same but getting error at from keras_text_summarization.library import Seq2SeqSummarizer
from keras_text_summarization.library import fit_text, i can see there is no two files what to do now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Conda install use :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I'm using conda for all my dependencies installation. 

I prefer not to use pip because I don't want to mix two package managers: 

"it’s a better idea to use the conda package manager for anything installed by the conda package manager. Using pip may have unexpected consequences when used in combination with conda" - https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-upgrade-pip-in-anaconda-python .

In addition: it's complaining about 'ModuleNotFoundError: 'keras_text_summarization' isn't keras_text_summarization part of the source code itself of the project and not one of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines at the starting of the file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```